# Query arrays using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of imported data:

```
array(3) {
  [1234]=>
  array(2) {
    ["item"]=>
    string(6) "scotch"
    ["type"]=>
    string(6) "Spirit"
  }
  [5678]=>
  array(2) {
    ["item"]=>
    string(4) "wine"
    ["type"]=>
    string(7) "Vintner"
  }
  [9012]=>
  array(2) {
    ["item"]=>
    string(11) "soft drinks"
    ["type"]=>
    string(3) "Pop"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make it say "Its in the Spirit section under code 1234"
I'm new to php so not sure I'm writing the for loop if function correctly. I keep getting "We are out of stock". Man I need a whisky. Help please

my code:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
$sheet1 = [];
if (($handle = fopen("sheet1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $sheet1[$data[0]] = [];
        $sheet1[$data[0]]['item'] = $data[1];
        $sheet1[$data[0]]['type'] = $data[2];
        $row++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
var_dump($sheet1);
$string = 'Where is scotch in shop';
echo $string;
$words = explode(' ', $string);
print_r($words);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); ++$i) {

    if (isset($sheet1[$words[$i]]['item'])) {
        echo "Its in the ".$sheet1[$words[$i]]['type']." section marked
        under code ".$sheet1[$words[$i]]['key']; 

    }
}
echo "We are out of stock";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change it to a foreach and then check for the existance of the word using `in_array()` it all looks a litle easier to understand.

```
foreach ($sheet1 as $key=>$sheet) {

    if ( in_array($sheet['item'], $words) ) {
        echo "Its in the {$sheet['type']} section marked under code $key";  

    }
}
```

Result

```
Its in the Spirit section marked under code 1234
```

Comment: thanks would you have any idea how to write that as an isset function. i heard that was much faster for bigger sheets and arrays.

Comment: Execution time is unmeasurable and report as 0 millisecs

Comment: Actually `isset` makes no sence in what you are trying to do. All that does is test if a variable is set or not. It does not test that the variable contains something specific that you are looking for